# Python's strip() function not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML that I want to scrape:

```
<div class="messaging-device">
     "
                 Text I want 
     "
     <span class="edit-panel">
          <a href="">Edit</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

And I have the following Python code to scrape it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(html, "lxml")
div = soup.find("div" {"class": "messaging-device"})
# div.get_text() returns 
# " 
#            Text I want
# Edit"
# so in order to get just "Text I want"
# I replaced div.get_text() with the following line
text = div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
print(text)
```

Unfortunately, text has many trailing newlines, so I changed

```
text = div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
```

to

```
text = div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0].strip()
```

But this change gets rid of "Text I want" entirely. Does anybody know I can properly get rid of trailing newlines?

Comment: First, if you want to get rid of just trailing whitespace, not both leading and trailing, use `rstrip`, not `strip`. Bur meanwhile, if you want us to debug your problem, you need to give us a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and can be debugged. It's hard to believe that the whole `text = … [0]` returned a string full of non-whitespace characters but adding `.strip()` to the end emptied it out, but if that really _is_ happening, we definitely need to be able to repro it to find the bug.

Comment: Strip, lstrip, and rstrip let you specify which characters will be stripped:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Comment: If you have trouble with `strip` alone, please post an example that illustrates the `strip` probkem -- we shouldn't see any `bs` code, since that's working for you.  Also, read the `strip` fgamily's documentation and resolve your understanding before posting here.

Comment: Does the HTML really contain the `"` characters around the text you want, or is that just how it's being displayed in the browser console? Use `View Source` to see the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as posted doesn't run. And, even after I guess at how to fix it to run, it does not actually do what you claim. But I'm pretty sure I know where the error is anyway.

This code does not return an empty string, but a `"`:

```
text = div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0].strip()
```

… and it's not because of `strip`. Because, Contrary to what you claim, this code does not include the text you want in the first place:

```
text = div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
```

… but rather `'"\n'`. So of course stripping that gives you an empty string.

---

If you print out the intermediate pieces, you can see why:

```
>>> div.get_text()
'\n     "\n                 Text I want \n     "\n     \nEdit\n\n'
>>> div.get_text().strip()
'"\n                 Text I want \n     "\n     \nEdit'
>>> div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)
['"\n', '                Text I want \n     "\n     \nEdit']
>>> div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
'"\n'
>>> div.get_text().strip().split(" ", 1)[0].strip()
'"'
```

It looks like what you *actually* want to do is find the text between the first two `"` characters, and then split that:

```
>>> div.get_text().strip().split('"', 2)[1].strip()
'Text I want'
```

---

But also, I think you're making things more complicated than they need to be by including all descendant text instead of just the immediate child text. If we don't have the `Edit` part to deal with, the whole thing is just the text you want surrounded by a complicated mix of spaces, newlines, and quotes… which we can strip out all in one go:

```
>>> div.contents[0]
'\n     "\n                 Text I want \n     "\n
>>> div.contents[0].strip(' \n"')
 'Text I want'
```